# Raills: Get SQL generated by delete_all

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I'm not particularly familiar with Ruby on Rails, but I'm troubleshooting an issue we're experiencing with a rake job that is supposed to be cleaning database tables.  The tables grow very large very quickly, and the query generated by ActiveRecord doesn't seem to be efficient enough to handle it.

The Ruby calls looks like this:

```
Source.where("id not IN (#{Log.select('DISTINCT source_id').to_sql})").delete_all
```

and this:

```
Log.joins(:report).where(:report_id => Report.where(cond)).delete_all
```

I'm trying to get at the SQL, so we can have our DBA's attempt to optimize it better.  I've noticed if I drop the ".delete_all" I can add a ".to_sql" which gives me the SELECT statement of the query, prior to the call to ".delete_all".  I'd like to see what SQL is being generated by that delete_all method though.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: What version of rails are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [fine manual](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-delete_all):

> **delete_all(conditions = nil)**
>
> Deletes the records matching `conditions` without instantiating the records first, and hence not calling the `destroy` method nor invoking callbacks. This is a single SQL DELETE statement that goes straight to the database, much more efficient than `destroy_all`.

So a `Model.delete_all(conditions)` ends up as

```
delete from models where conditions
```

When you say `Model.where(...).delete_all`, the `conditions` for the `delete_all` come from the `where` calls so these are the same:

```
Model.delete_all(conditions)
Model.where(conditions).delete_all
```

Applying that to your case:

```
Source.where("id not IN (#{Log.select('DISTINCT source_id').to_sql})").delete_all
```

you should see that you're running:

```
delete from sources
where id not in (
    select distinct source_id
    from logs
)
```

If you run your code in a development console you should see the SQL in the console or the Rails logs but it will be as above.

As far as optimization goes, my first step would be to drop the DISTINCT. DISTINCT usually isn't cheap and `IN` doesn't care about duplicates anyway so `not in (select distinct ...)` is probably pointless busy work. Then maybe an index on `source_id` would help, the query optimizer might be able to slurp the `source_id` list straight out of the index without having to do a table scan to find them. Of course, query optimization is a bit of a dark art so these simple steps may or may not work.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use raw Arel syntax, similar to a simplified version of what [ActiveRecord::Relation#delete_all](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/f4538aa5865da5f16b707d34aa733a5e2353f2fd/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation.rb#L577) does.

```
relation = Model.where(...)
arel = relation.arel
stmt = Arel::DeleteManager.new
stmt.from(arel.join_sources.empty? ? Model.arel_table : arel.source)
stmt.wheres = arel.constraints
sql = Model.connection.to_sql(stmt, relation.bound_attributes)
print sql
```

This will give you the generated delete sql. Here's an example using postgres as the sql adapter

```
relation = User.where('email ilike ?', '%@gmail.com')
arel = relation.arel
stmt = Arel::DeleteManager.new
stmt.from(arel.join_sources.empty? ? User.arel_table : arel.source)
stmt.wheres = arel.constraints
sql = User.connection.to_sql(stmt, relation.bound_attributes)    
=> DELETE FROM "users" WHERE (email ilike '%@gmail.com')
```

Comment: I updated the ActiveRecord::Relation#delete_all link with a permalink to its current position. Also, it looks like the `relation.bound_attributes` argument is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

`ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)` should show you all the SQL generated by rails on your console.